# php/oop/mvc order of operation with markdown files (no db)

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, flat-file

***Goal***: understand whether this implemented order/logic of operation indeed belongs to the **C** part of MV**C**.

***Situation***: I have nearly finished a simple note-taking site with markdown files. No database is used except for authentication. The lack of database, however, makes it difficult to know if I am neglecting the **M** of **M**VC.

Because I did not want to have the `.md` extension as part of the pretty url, I am heavily relying on the PageController to settle the order of operation.

From the Controller, PageController inherits the constructed filesystem/Flysystem(fs), twig, and the "$app" that processes any of the three scenarios.

It first checks to see if a `param.md` exists and then whether `param` is a directory. If none of the above, then it's a new note. In each case, it uses a corresponding method set by the Application ($app) that processes and returns an array (title, breadcrumbs, content/directory listing, new template etc).

```
<?php 
namespace App\Controller;
class PageController extends Controller {

public function Page($param){
  $file=$param.'.md';
  if ($this->fs->has($file)) {
    $data=$this->app->setNote($file);
    return $this->app->render('note.twig',$data)
  }
  elseif ($this->fs->has($param)) {
    $data=$this->app->setFolder($param);
    return $this->app->render('folder.twig',$data)
  }
  else {
    $data=$this->app->setNew($param);
    return $this->app->render('new.twig',$data)
   }  
 }
}
```

Per ["PHP the Right Way"](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html#model-view-controller):

> Controllers handle the request, process the data returned from models and load views to send in the response.

Although my code *works* and gets the job done, it does not appear to the be right way because the main App is doing the processing. I guess I could just move the Application.php in the Models folder, but would that make it adhere to "right way"? Should I use a Middleware before the PageController gets to work?

It may seem silly to ask about a code that just works, but my goal is to better understand/learn the current wisdom's ways when dealing with flat-files.

Comment: Quick side-note: I am not using any (micro)framework to force myself to understand each of the php cogs.

Answer (score -1):

Regardless of whether you are 'database-less', the data is being stored / accessed in the `.md` files.

Access to them should be abstracted to a Model. You should create a `File.find` object + method, and/or a `File.find_or_create`.  Then

```
$file = File.find_or_create($param);
$render_type = $file.type . '.twig';
return $this->app->render($render_type, $file.data);
```

Put all your if logic in the Model.